# Sequelize.js: How to set foreignkey in two 1:N relationships between two models?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

What I want to do is to make the relationships that `User` sell or buy `Item`. To do it with Sequelize and MySQL, I wrote code like this.

```
db.User.hasMany(db.Item);
db.Item.belongsTo(db.User, { as: "buyer" });

db.User.hasMany(db.Item);
db.Item.belongsTo(db.User, { as: "seller" });
```

However, this code makes an error. I think `db.User.hasMany(db.Item)` creates `userId` in `Item`, and the code make that happen twice. But the problem is, I don't want to add `userId` in Item, but `buyerId` and `sellerId`. How do I need to set options in `db.User.hasMany(db.Item)`?

Comment: Why are you trying to define `db.User.hasMany(db.Item)` twice? The two lines are identical. What difference do you expect executing it twice? Would it not work if you just left off the redundant line? A User has many Items (either as seller or buyer) and using `blongsTo` twice you define two _different_ relations from Item to User.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have `buyerId` and `sellerId` columns in `Item`, this should do:

```
db.User.hasMany(db.Item);
db.Item.belongsTo(db.User, { as: "buyer", targetKey: "buyerId"});
db.Item.belongsTo(db.User, { as: "seller", targetKey: "sellerId" });
```

If not `User.id` is the primary key, you should also add `foreignKey: [key name]` to both options.

See [reference manual](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsTo)

Comment: I tried it, but when I print the fields of ```Item``` in MySQL console, ```Item``` has ```userId``` field. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two 1-M relationships between User and Item like this:

```
db.User.hasMany(db.Item, {
  foreignKey: 'sellerId',
});
db.User.hasMany(db.Item, {
  foreignKey: 'buyerId',
});
db.Item.belongsTo(db.User, {
  foreignKey: 'sellerId',
  constraints: false,
  as: 'seller'
});
db.Item.belongsTo(db.User, {
  foreignKey: 'buyerId',
  constraints: false,
  as: 'buyer'
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but when I print the fields of ```Item``` in MySQL console, ```Item``` has ```userId``` field. How do I remove it?

Comment: You can remove field from mysql table like this: ALTER TABLE item DROP COLUMN userId; For details: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_drop_column.asp